# Positioning HTML5 Jquery player on plain html page

Tags: css, html, positioning, media

The layout in question is here: http://www.davedaranjo.com/media.html

This is probably an issue in standard positioning with css, but I've tried every positioning combination I can think of to achieve this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFOGy.jpg

Every time I try to move the player anywhere on the page, it positions itself at the bottom, even below the footer. I've even tried putting the content in a table with the links and video in the left td and the player in the right, but the player won't even sit in the table. I've also tried a number of positioning tags in the css file and at best, it will move if I give it a fixed position, but because the rest of the layout isn't fixed (and isn't on the rest of the site), that's not a viable solution.

I realize this is probably something fundamental that I'm missing here, but any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look at the source of that page and saw quite a few things i would change, so i will not go into detail but maybe this will get you started.

You could try floating your main div (look for `<div align="center">` in your code) with css `float: left;` and also make your player inline-block like so;

```
.ttw-music-player { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Ok, that put the player down at the bottom left of the page in a fixed position. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: I've tried so many different positioning styles and no matter which I use, the player and it's content refuse to appear above any other content on the page, regardless of the player's div placement in the html code or any positioning attributes assigned to it. I'm getting desperate here.